# Salt-stack list all available states

Tags: salt-stack

I already searched the doc and was not able to find an satisfying answer. Is it possible to get something like salt 'machine' state.list. To get all states that could be potentially applied?

I know there is the high state / top / lowstate, but if i want to search for a particular state i always need to go through the folder structure manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this...

Is a little one liner command you can set as an alias

```
cd /srv/salt; tree -fC -P '*.sls' --noreport * | sed 's/.sls//g' | sed 's|\/|.|g'
```

Comment: but shouldn't you do it for each folder in file_roots ?

Answer (score 14):

Use `salt '*' state.show_sls '*'` on master and
`salt-call state.show_sls '*'` on minions